# Which one is a correct way to write: a) two functions problems, or b) two-function problems?

Tags: compound-adjectives

I am wondering which of the following are grammatically correct?

*Example sentence*:

a) We evaluate two-function problems in the example.

b) We evaluate two functions problems in the example.

If none of the above, then any other suggestion? Thank you.

---

Other possibility: "problems with two functions" makes more sense to me rather than option b) above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having corrected the tag, its description gives a hint to the answer:

> A compound adjective is when two or more adjectives are combined to modify a noun. In many instances, such compounds are hyphenated.

Adjectives in English are not inflected for number. We talk of *red apples* not *reds apples,* even when there may be several *reds* (shades of red) involved.

It's the same as *ten-dollar bill, ten-pound note, six-foot man, thirty-kilo bag of potatoes...* All of those adjectives have a singular *dollar, pound, foot, kilo.* The hyphens make it clear that the adjective comprises two words.

While a *ten dollar bill* is understandable, something like "six star fish" may not be. That rather poor example could refer to six creatures or a single fish with six stars. The hyphen is the customary way of representing which words are linked, and it can be used in all compound adjectives.

Thus you need a hyphen and a singular form: "two-function problems"